# php session data getting lost

Tags: php, session

i created a sign in page that proceeds to a new page.
when i sign in,session does get created but when i open a new page ,it says sign in to view.
code was working fine until i tried to create a signout script.

```
if($_SESSION['user_name'])
{
    echo '<h3> Hello ' . $_SESSION['user_name'] . '. Not you?</h3> <a href="signout.php">Sign out</a>';
}
else
{
    echo '<a href="signin.php">Sign in</a> or <a href="sign up">create an account</a>.';
}
```

this is the script on the redirected page. it always shows the second sentence.

Comment: Are you using `session_start()` everywhere?

Comment: Where is your session_start()????

Comment: sorry i forgot to place session_start(); in the code.

Comment: did a very silly mistake .

Answer (score 2):

Place `session_start();` on the top of your script

And note that you must not output anything before using `session_start()`.

Also I recommend you using encoding `UTF-8 without BOM` that can help you some mystic empty string issue.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put "session_start();" at the beginning in every one of your script files.